# Exclude scrollbar of Java SWT Browser from event

Tags: java, browser, swt, scrollbar

There's an SWT Browser on a packed composite. I added a listener on SWT.MouseDown event, so when the Browser is clicked on my custom method runs.
It works fine if the Browser has no scrollbar. My problem is that when Browser is resized a scrollbar automatically appears on the right side of the Browser and when there is a SWT.MouseDown event on the scrollbar my custom method runs, which in not correct behavior.

If the Browser has a scrollbar SWT.MouseDown event shouldn't execute my custom method.
Is there a way to achive this?

It's the Browsers own scrollbar, Browsers is called with SWT.NONE style, so
methods getVerticalBar() or getHorizontalBar() both return null.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to work it around:
The scrollbar can be controlled by tags in the html string.

Add this to the html string if I want the scrollbar to be hidden.

```
<body style='overflow:hidden;'>
```

And this to be always shown:

```
<body style='overflow:scroll;'
```

I added the later and put a condition in my listener, to only execute my method if the user clicked on any part of the widget but the scrollbar.

```
    switch (event.type) {
                    case SWT.MouseDown:
                        if (getSize().x - event.x > SCROLLBAR_WIDTH && getSize().y - event.y > SCROLLBAR_WIDTH) {
// Do this when clicking on widget, but not on scrollbar.
}
```

The SCROLLBAR_WIDTH value is based on trial & error, so it's not perfect but hopefully will do the purpose.